# Why does the property builtin work in conjunction with classes but not outside of them?

Tags: python, properties, built-in

I can do

```
class Foo(object):
    x = property(lambda _: 123)        
f = Foo()
f.x
```

to get `123`

However, if I try

```
p = property(lambda : 123)
p
```

I get

```
<property object at 0x108f2f3b8>
```

Now I understand that an member of a class instance is not the same thing as a regular variable but I'm not sure **what** exactly makes this behavior different.

Does the fact that you instantiate a class somehow do extra binding on `property` objects? Is it a special case or is it a behavior I can take advantage in other situations and extend? Related - are `property` objects useful outside of a class declaration? Or is it just for this specific case?

Comment: I think you're looking for the [descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html).

Comment: Oh wait....`@property` and `property(..)` are *the same* thing, not like a different type of thing that happen to have the same name? Ok...

Comment: Correct, `@name` is just syntactic sugar.